# How do C# Programmers effectively use "using ___;"?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner C# developer and I'm branching out into looking at certain parts of what some more advanced bits of code. However, I cannot wrap my head around how developers and programmers use the "using" commands effectively. I understand how they work, and if they are a public class file they can have their methods accessed, but how do programmers know from picking up an API how to use it?

Sorry if this question seems like a total breeze and as though I've misunderstood the concept entirely (maybe I have, haha) but it seems like something where without extensively going through the API and it's documentation, most people can chew through these things quite easily.

Comment: You have to rely on documentation or disassembly information. For instance, look at [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1). It shows right at the top what the namespace is. In order to use that, you should include a `using System.Linq;` statement.

Comment: Welcome to SO Leopawed.  This question is too broad to answer - it's hard to even tell what your stumbling blolck is.  Try adding in some context: "Can I do X" - "Is it used for Y?".  As far as it stands, this question seems to be "What does this mean" which is best answered by the docs as itsme86 said

Comment: Honestly I can't recall the last time I added or edited a `using` directive manually.  Visual Studio generally handles it for you.  When you try to reference a class, if that class exists then Visual Studio will suggest either entering the fully-qualified namespace or adding a `using` directive.  I almost always choose the latter and continue on my way.  (If the class isn't found then a `using` directive won't solve that.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not sure if you are aware of not, but the `using` directive does not actually "import" or start "using" anything. `using System;` merely tells the compiler that whenever you use something like `DateTime`, it will check `System.DateTime` and try to look for the type there. In fact, you can write in C# without using the `using` directive at all (unless you need to resolve a naming conflict), but of course the program will become unnecessarily "wordy".

As for the other part of your question, you don't begin writing a C# program starting with `using`. You first have to find the proper "tools" (classes) for the problem you are trying to solve by the program, and only then add `using` so that you can work with them efficiently without typing the namespace over and over. Moreover, most modern IDEs will add the directive automatically, either when you create a new file (adding some common namespaces), or when you use a class in a namespace that you forgot to import with `using`.